# I want to get back these folder

Tags: git, github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOfFY.png)

Accidently I commit and push. Now some of my file gone. How can I get back these file using git command?

Comment: `git revert`? This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit

Answer (score 2):

If the files were only removed in the last commit do `git log -1 --name-only`.  This will give you a list of the files.  Using `git checkout HEAD~2 -- <filenames>`, you can get the files back as they were before being deleted.

If they were in multiple commits do `git log --name-only <name of folder>` and not the commit  that they were removed in.  Then you can do `git checkout <SHA>~ -- <file>` and this will get them back.  The `~` is a shortcut for the previous commit.

The above is useful if there were other changes that you want to keep in the commit.  If not, you can just `git revert` the commit and things will be returned as well.